# Call an event within another event JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so i have a grid of divs as shown below:

```
<div class="check1"></div>
<div class="check1"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="check1"></div>
<div class="check1"></div>
```

In my jquery i check if one of the div's have been clicked using:

```
$('.check1').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');
});
```

What i would like to do is if a div is cliced and held down but the cursor moves over another div i would also like that div to change color. I tried this example but the mouseover event is called regardless if the mouse down event has been called.

```
$('.check1').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','blue');

    $('.check1').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});
```

Is this possible and if so what am I doing wrong / what do i need to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple `flag` concept

**Code:**

```
var flag = 0;
$('.check1').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    flag = 1;
}).mouseup(function () {
    flag = 0;
}).mouseover(function () {
    if (flag) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/RXc5d/)

Comment: Absolutly perfect. Cant believe i didnt think of that to be honest. Thanks for the quick reply and the example link. +1

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way:)

```
$('.check1').on('mouseover mousedown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 1){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLARP/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.check1').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color','blue'});

    $(this).bind('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'});
    }).bind('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'green'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have simply forgotten to unbind the `mouseover` event.

```
$('.check1').mousedown(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue')

    $('.check1').on('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue')
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $('.check1').off('mouseover');
    });
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vREzg/